# Planet at the end of Solo: A Star Wars Story

Tags: star-wars, solo-a-star-wars-story

At the end of *Solo: A Star Wars Story*, Han Solo catches up with Lando Calrissian on a forested planet. In the scene, Han wins the Millennium Falcon. What is the name of the planet where Han beats Lando?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Numidian Prime

From [Star Wars databank](https://www.starwars.com/databank/numidian-prime),

> On the jungle planet of Numidian Prime, Han Solo famously beat Lando Calrissian at his own game -- cheating at the card game sabacc -- and walked away the new owner of the Millennium Falcon.